# OpenEXR Multilayer Alpha Channel Issues - Blender to After Effects

Tags: compositing-nodes, transparency, viewlayers

I am working on a project which required some after effects compositing. I'm having trouble with an OpenEXR Multilayer Sequence.

I'm having trouble with a few materials and their alpha channels. Unfortunately, the alpha channel exported on a particular viewlayer seems to be muddled and pixelated. Is there a reason this particular material does not work with transparency for After Effects? It seems to work in the blender compositor, but I need AE for some other worflows and masking with this project. Anyone seen anything similar? I don't have a lot of experience with EXR or compositing, so perhaps it's something I'm doing wrong in AE and this is the wrong spot for this question.

Materials -

[image]

[image]

Blender Viewport -
[image]

After Effects Compositing
[image]

Blender Compositor -
[image]

This is another scene where one of the materials which seems to have worked in my test file but not in the scene here -

[image]

AE comp

[image]

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-fkRqkXH2IS)

Comment: This looks more like and after effect question. Did you change the color space inside AE? OPENEXR is in linear color space

Comment: Yep, there are a few issues with converting Blender's filmic to AE linear but that doesn't seem to be the transparency issue. I actually think it has to do with the view layer alpha channels using a holdout mask, but only with certain cycles materials. Something I realized is that the alpha channel is not denoised in the same way that RGB is denoised. I will try with higher samples and denoising the alpha channel and the compositor to see if this has a difference. Maybe the velvet+transparency is just confusing for blender.

Comment: Update - it appears using "convert premultiplied" in the blender alpha over node yields the same result as my after effects comp!! Now to get after effects to not use their version of this option...